# Make "nsfetchedresultcontroller" a synonym for "nsfetchedresultscontrolle"

Tags: support, stack-overflow, synonym-request

I suggest to make [nsfetchedresultcontroller](/questions/tagged/nsfetchedresultcontroller) a synonym for [nsfetchedresultscontrolle](/questions/tagged/nsfetchedresultscontrolle).

Both tags are about the `NSFetchedResultsController` class in the Apple "Core Data" framework, and it is obvious that both tag names are different attempts to cope with the limit of 25 characters.

[nsfetchedresultscontrolle](/questions/tagged/nsfetchedresultscontrolle) has currently 780 questions and has a tag wiki, so this should be the "master".

[nsfetchedresultcontroller](/questions/tagged/nsfetchedresultcontroller) has 83 questions and no wiki, so this should be the synonym.

(I proposed this already using the "suggest tag synonym" form, but the request is pending for 5 month now. Probably few people review the "pending request".)

Comment: Is there any way of making these tags more "human-reader"-friendly?

Comment: @Shai: This is probably a question for the administrators. As far as I can see it, the tag names use only lower case letters and a few special characters. - In this particular case, `NSFetchedResultsController` has 26 characters and there seems no sensible way of shortening it, so I suggested to make the more established one the "master".

Comment: @Shai: I probably misunderstood your question, so this is another try to respond to that: There are already many tags for Objective-C classes in Apple's Cocoa frameworks, using the class name (converted to lowercase) as tag name: nsarray, nsdictionary, uiviewcontroller, etc. I would therefore probably vote against using a different "human-reader friendly" tag, if it does not fit into this scheme. But perhaps somebody has a good suggestion.