# Tag badges awarded far too late

Tags: support, tag-badges

On August 10 2017 (2018-08-10 04:04:37Z to be precise), I was awarded both the
[bronze tag badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/7203/nsfetchedresultscontroller)
(simultaneously with 4 other users) and the [silver tag badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/7201/nsfetchedresultscontroller)
for [[nsfetchedresultscontroller]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nsfetchedresultscontroller).

Why were the tag badges awarded so late?

My current score is 467 for 111 answers, and my [last activity](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a1187415%20%5bnsfetchedresultscontroller%5d%20is%3aanswer) for that tag is from April 2017. I did not earn much reputation
for [nsfetchedresultscontroller] in recent months, so I would have expected
to earn the silver tag badge before April 2017, and the bronze
tag badge much earlier.

Also it is extremely unlikely that
the criteria for the bronze and the silver tag badges are fulfilled on the
same day, or that 5 users earned the tag badge at the same date.

Is this a bug or is there some additional condition that must be
satisfied for tag badges, which wasn't satisfied before August 10?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Until recently the maximum tag length was 25 characters. This [changed to 35 recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197889/raising-the-25-chars-limit-for-tags/299490#299490).

Previously there was a tag called [nsfetchedresultscontrolle](/questions/tagged/nsfetchedresultscontrolle) (which lacked a final ending r).

The [tag was renamed by a moderator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253564/i-just-found-a-tag-which-was-cut-off-can-it-be-fixed) to [nsfetchedresultscontroller](/questions/tagged/nsfetchedresultscontroller) hence your award. Your score on the old tag now counts as a score on the new tag. The rename happened on August 9th so you got the badges when the badge award process ran a few hours later.

Comment: Thanks! – Both Q&As that you link to state that the tag *can* be longer now. But where would one find that this particular tag actually *has* been renamed?

Comment: That would be the [status-completed on this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253564/i-just-found-a-tag-which-was-cut-off-can-it-be-fixed) which is linked in my answer already.

Answer (score 6):

The tag has been renamed. 'nsfetchedresultscontroller' is 26 characters, and the tag length limit used to be 25. [Recently, that limit has been changed to 35](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299490/295232). I'm not sure how the tag was called before, but apparently renaming the tag caused the badges to be re-awarded or at least re-dated.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. Indeed it was called [nsfetchedresultscontrolle] before. I should have noticed the difference because I posted about these tags some years ago (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164344/make-nsfetchedresultcontroller-a-synonym-for-nsfetchedresultscontrolle, posted on MSO and auto-migrated to MSE).